# phonegap php email gmail

Tags: php, cordova

Im doing a small app using phonegap, my contains a form that will send the informatin to my email, im using smtp gmail to do this, but the gmail code is in php is there a way to do this without using php, or using php ?

Comment: You will have to write your own SMTP plugin if you want to do it natively from the app itself. There is an outdated plugin written for PhoneGap 2.0, you can take a look https://github.com/jlmoga/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/emailPlugin

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can send emails using the email composer plugin: 
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

You can send your emails using that.